# Android Studio 2.3.2 MainActivity is not displayed

Tags: android

I have created API 21(values-v21) Launcher App.I have used SharedPreferences in it.My project has Second Activity which is called in MainActivity.

The problem I am facing is how to display MainActivity on mobile phone(Samsung galaxy S4).It is still displaying "Hello World" message.

Thanks
Abhijit.

Comment: Have you heard of an Intent?

Comment: startActivity(this, MainActivity.class); should solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an Example to explain how to navigate to another Activity in Android (There can be many different ways.) Just Grab the concept.

Here I would like to have a Simple button in your first Activity (which displays *Hello World*)

1. Go to the first_activity.xml file & add button

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <!-- layout elements -->
   <Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Second Page"
       android:onClick="goToSecondActivity" />
   <!-- even more layout elements -->
   ```

   Now Android will look for the onClick method goToSecondActivity() only in the first Activity.
2. Now Write the code to navigate to second activity when click the button on first activity

   ```
   /** Called when the user taps the SecondPage button */
   public void goToSecondActivity(View view) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
   }
   ```

There is a nice Guide from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) if you can follow

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent)
```